# Probability Help! (X,Y) ~ f(x,y) = 8xy $I_D(x,y)$

Tags: probability

a) $f_X (x) =$ ?

b) $P( X + Y < \frac{1}{2}) =$ ?

c) $f_Y(y \,| \, X = \frac{3}{4}) =$ ?

d) $P( Y < \frac{1}{2} \, | \, X = \frac{3}{4}) = $ ?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!!

Here is my work so far...

a) To get marginal density of $x$, I need to integrate $f(x,y)$ once with respect to $y$. From the drawing, we see the appropriate bounds for integration is $0$ and $x$. So we have 
$∫8xydy$ from $0$ to $x$, yielding $4x^3$ for $0<x<1$.

b) First we need to understand what exactly is $X + Y < \frac{1}{2}$. This the line between $(.5,0)$ and the endpoint where it intersects with $y=x$, so that I end up with an isosceles triangle. You can see that the appropriate double integral is 
$∫∫8xydydx$, over $(0,.5-x)$ for $y$ and $(0,.5)$ for $x$. Then split the integral into two parts to make it easier ?

c) $f(y|X)= f(x,y)/f(x)= 8xy/(4x^3)$ Then plug in $x = .75$ ?

d) Now that I have part c), I can integrate $y$ from $0$ to $.5$ ?

[image: Is this what $I_D (x,y)$ is?]

Comment: It's shorthand notation for $f(x,y)=8xy$ when $(x,y)\in D$ and $f(x,y)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: And D is $x \leq y \wedge 0 \leq x \leq 1 \wedge 0 \leq y \leq 1$

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense.

Comment: Does my work above look like its on the right track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\operatorname{\bf I}_D(x,y)$ is an **indicator function**; a characteristic equation that has the value of $1$ when the argument exists within the domain, and a value if $0$ when it does not.  Here the argument is $(x,y)$ and the domain is $D$.

This is sometimes written as: ${\large\bf 1}_D(x,y)$.

It is compact notation for the piecewise function:

$$\operatorname{\bf I}_D(x,y) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{if } 0\leq y \leq x\leq 1 \\ 0 & \text{elsewise}\end{cases}$$

---

a) $f_X (x) =\int 8xy\operatorname{\bf I}_D(x,y) \operatorname{d} y = \int_0^x 8xy \operatorname{d} y \operatorname{\bf I}_{x\in[0,1]}(x)= 4x^3 \operatorname{\bf I}_{x\in[0,1]}(x)$

b) $P( X + Y < \frac{1}{2}) =$ ? : Simply observe what portion of the domain $D$ is below the line $x=\frac 1 2 - y$?

d) $P( Y < \frac{1}{2} \mid X = \frac{3}{4}) = $ ? : Find the line segment at $x=\frac 34$ what portion lies below $y=\frac 1 2$.

Comment: Does my added work above seem to be on the right track?